# env variable in JSON file in public folder of CRA

Tags: json, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have this `config.json` file located in my public folder, in which I need to put some params different in development and in production modes. I fetch it when my app loads (`fetch('config.json').then()`).

Is there a way that my `config.json` file looks like that :

```
{
  "url": "%REACT_APP_URL%"
}
```

Of course, the code above doesn't work : is there another solution ?

Comment: Why do you want to fetch `config.json` instead of e.g. having a `config.js` file in which you export environment variables and just import that in your app? `export const url = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;`

Comment: in case the config.json could be modified afterwards, once the build is done and won't change

Comment: I see. Interesting. Wouldn't it be easier to make a new build when you want to change the settings? Then you will also have access to the settings straight away and it doesn't have to wait for a network request to finish, which might be easier to handle.

Comment: If there is no other option, yes, but this is kind of a request I have, so I try my best to answer it, if I can !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app, you don't need to use a config file. Simple create a .env file in the root directory and add your environment variables:

```
URL=REACT_APP_URL
```

In your app, simple do something like

```
const url = process.env.REACT_APP_URL
```

Check out my post https://medium.com/@selom/nice-article-a446406f4447